# Accepting large input from user - raw_input()

Tags: python, raw-input

I am trying to get `3,000` numbers from the user using `raw_input()` and adding them to a list. However, only a part of the input is captured.

```
numbers = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())
print len(numbers)
```

Say, the numbers are :

```
for _ in range(3000):
    print _,
```

Interestingly, this works fine if done in the python shell, but if I save the script and run from the terminal, I get `len(numbers)` as only 1041.

PS : If I change the numbers from `3000` to `10,000`, `2048` get accepted.

Comment: Did you actually run this, type in 3000 integers, and check the result?

Comment: I saved the integers in a file and pasted them in the terminal.

Comment: Many terminals have character limits per line. It'd make more sense to `cat` or `type` the text file and pipe it into your Python program (or have your program actually open a text file with `with open(myfile) as f:...`).

Comment: Do what @TigerhawkT3 says to do but I don't see why you would ever want to do this... Just use a file

Comment: Run your program like this:
`python myscript.py < largefile`. That will avoid the paste problem you are likely hitting.

Comment: I have to accept from the terminal straightaway, it will be run this way when being used.

Comment: I don't understand how any user would ever type 3000 number into a terminal, while using a program. I smell an XY problem here

Comment: I opened the python shell, wrote the loop I mentioned in the question, copied the output, `Ctrl-D`ed from the shell, fired up the script using `$ python scripy.py` and pasted the result. Hit enter. Just `1041`, no `3000`

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively, 100% sure that your users are going to sit there and type 3000 (or 10,000) integers into the terminal (assuming that was technically feasible for most terminals, which it isn't)? Even you are that sure, I can guarantee you that those users aren't going to enter 3000 numbers _correctly_ like that.

Comment: When you copy from the shell, it might be inserting newline characters at the end of each visible line. Copy these integers into a text file first to make sure it's all one line. But, again, this input method is unrealistic, so you should pursue some other method like reading a text file.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, there is no new line being inserted. If it were, Python would print the `len`, exit and the remaining lines would litter the terminal

Comment: When you paste the line into the terminal, is the last integer in the line the correct one (e.g. `3000`)?

Comment: Yes, it is rightly `2999`.